How to replace package path easily?
Project/
├── a/
│   ├── core/
│   │   └── com.blabla.hi.sofbs
│   └── api/
│       └── com.blabla.hi.sofbs
└── b/
    ├── core/
    │   └── com.blabla.hi.sofbq
    └── api/
        └── com.blabla.hi.sofbq

to
Project/
├── a/
│   ├── core/
│   │   └── us.bla.sofbs
│   └── api/
│       └── us.bla.sofbs
└── b/
    ├── core/
    │   └── us.bla.sofbq
    └── api/
        └── us.bla.sofbq

I want to refactor packages in my project modules but I don't want to refactor each package one by one because the project has many modules. How can I do this quickly and easily?

An IDE will do this sort of refactoring for you.  It's somewhat manual but can be done in groups.

Yeah, so I want to know how to do that.

right click on a package (typically the most nested), click refactor and click rename

To rename packages in IntelliJ IDEA, right-click the package you want to rename in the Project tool window, and from the context menu select Refactor | Rename (Shift + F6).
If the package you want to rename represents multiple directories, IntelliJ IDEA will give you the option to rename "Selected directories only" or "All directories".

For more information, see the documentation:

Rename a directory or a module
Rename a package﻿


In this case, I can rename only "a.b.c" to "a.b.f" not "a.b" or "a" or "d.e.f".
How think aboud this?
Can I get some idea?

@SB_STOPDL In that case you may have to create the new directories and move the files. You can move files in the Project tool window by selecting them and dragging-dropping them in the new directory.
